# Package can't import cython library in the egg

Tags: python, cython, setuptools, egg

I can use my package from its folder, but as soon as I install it as an egg package, cython-based modules can't get imported.

I have the following package structure

```
src/
├── mypkg/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── myfile.py
├── cython/
│   ├── fastcode.pyx
setup.py
```

The module `myfile.py` imports `import fastcode`.  In `setup.py`, I have

```
setup(
    name='mypkg',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(where="src"),
    package_dir={'':'src'},
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules=df_ext_modules,
)
```

I also have in `setup.cfg`,

```
[build_ext]
build-lib=src/mypkg
```

If I run `python setup.py install`, the cython code gets compiled and creates `fastcode.pyd` (or `fastcode.so` in Linux) in `mypkg` folder as instructed by the config file.

Now, if I go to the `mypkg` folder, and run `python`, I can safely do `import mypkg.myfile`.
However, when I run python from some other folder (such that the installed `.egg` file gets used) I get error `ImportError: No module named fastcode`.

I tried to add

```
package_data={
    'mypkg': ['*.pyd', '*.so']
},
```

to `setup.py`, this adds `fastcode.pyd` to the egg file (by exploring the unzipped version), but still doesn't work for importing.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to fix it in my case: had to remove `setup.cfg`. For those who are interested, the problem is that with the new setup, the `.egg` file also contains generated `fastcode.py` file, and `fastcode.pyc` file, not just `fastcode.pyd` file (which I would expect by looking at `mypkg` after the compilations with the previous setup where only `.pyd` files were present).